# Why won't the divisibility show up correctly when executing my loop?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

In the output, state whether the each integer is 'odd' or 'even' in the output.

If the number is divisible by three, instead of stating that the number is odd or even, state
that the number is 'divisible by three'.

If the number is divisible by both two and three, instead of saying that the number is odd,
even or divisible by three; state that the number is 'divisible by two and three'.

Below is what I'm seeing in the my attempt and the output in the console.  Why are some of the entries being replicated?  Not understanding what's wrong in my logic here.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is even" );
  } else {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is odd");
  }

    if(i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by three");
  }

    if(i % 2 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by two and three");
  }

}
```

`

```
(index):37 The number 1 is odd
(index):35 The number 2 is even
(index):37 The number 3 is odd
(index):41 The number 3 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 4 is even
(index):37 The number 5 is odd
(index):35 The number 6 is even
(index):41 The number 6 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 6 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 7 is odd
(index):35 The number 8 is even
(index):37 The number 9 is odd
(index):41 The number 9 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 10 is even
(index):37 The number 11 is odd
(index):35 The number 12 is even
(index):41 The number 12 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 12 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 13 is odd
(index):35 The number 14 is even
(index):37 The number 15 is odd
(index):41 The number 15 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 16 is even
(index):37 The number 17 is odd
(index):35 The number 18 is even
(index):41 The number 18 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 18 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 19 is odd
(index):35 The number 20 is even
(index):37 The number 21 is odd
(index):41 The number 21 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 22 is even
(index):37 The number 23 is odd
(index):35 The number 24 is even
(index):41 The number 24 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 24 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 25 is odd
(index):35 The number 26 is even
(index):37 The number 27 is odd
(index):41 The number 27 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 28 is even
(index):37 The number 29 is odd
(index):35 The number 30 is even
(index):41 The number 30 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 30 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 31 is odd
(index):35 The number 32 is even
(index):37 The number 33 is odd
(index):41 The number 33 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 34 is even
(index):37 The number 35 is odd
(index):35 The number 36 is even
(index):41 The number 36 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 36 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 37 is odd
(index):35 The number 38 is even
(index):37 The number 39 is odd
(index):41 The number 39 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 40 is even
(index):37 The number 41 is odd
(index):35 The number 42 is even
(index):41 The number 42 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 42 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 43 is odd
(index):35 The number 44 is even
(index):37 The number 45 is odd
(index):41 The number 45 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 46 is even
(index):37 The number 47 is odd
(index):35 The number 48 is even
(index):41 The number 48 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 48 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 49 is odd
(index):35 The number 50 is even
(index):37 The number 51 is odd
(index):41 The number 51 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 52 is even
(index):37 The number 53 is odd
(index):35 The number 54 is even
(index):41 The number 54 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 54 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 55 is odd
(index):35 The number 56 is even
(index):37 The number 57 is odd
(index):41 The number 57 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 58 is even
(index):37 The number 59 is odd
(index):35 The number 60 is even
(index):41 The number 60 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 60 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 61 is odd
(index):35 The number 62 is even
(index):37 The number 63 is odd
(index):41 The number 63 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 64 is even
(index):37 The number 65 is odd
(index):35 The number 66 is even
(index):41 The number 66 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 66 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 67 is odd
(index):35 The number 68 is even
(index):37 The number 69 is odd
(index):41 The number 69 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 70 is even
(index):37 The number 71 is odd
(index):35 The number 72 is even
(index):41 The number 72 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 72 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 73 is odd
(index):35 The number 74 is even
(index):37 The number 75 is odd
(index):41 The number 75 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 76 is even
(index):37 The number 77 is odd
(index):35 The number 78 is even
(index):41 The number 78 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 78 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 79 is odd
(index):35 The number 80 is even
(index):37 The number 81 is odd
(index):41 The number 81 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 82 is even
(index):37 The number 83 is odd
(index):35 The number 84 is even
(index):41 The number 84 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 84 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 85 is odd
(index):35 The number 86 is even
(index):37 The number 87 is odd
(index):41 The number 87 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 88 is even
(index):37 The number 89 is odd
(index):35 The number 90 is even
(index):41 The number 90 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 90 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 91 is odd
(index):35 The number 92 is even
(index):37 The number 93 is odd
(index):41 The number 93 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 94 is even
(index):37 The number 95 is odd
(index):35 The number 96 is even
(index):41 The number 96 is divisible by three
(index):45 The number 96 is divisible by two and three
(index):37 The number 97 is odd
(index):35 The number 98 is even
(index):37 The number 99 is odd
(index):41 The number 99 is divisible by three
(index):35 The number 100 is even
```

Example of correct output:

```
The number '1' is odd.
The number '2' is even.
The number '3' is divisible by three.
...
The number '6' is divisible by two and three.
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you saying that there should only be one result per number? For example, you've got 3 entires of 6 because it's an even number, it's divisible by 3 and also divisible by 2 and 3. This means all three of you if statements conditions are met and therefore spitting out the console.log message

Comment: @mwilson yeah.  I put an example in my original post on how it's supposed to look

Comment: Well you check for *just* divisibility by 3 *before* you check for divisibility by both 2 and 3. If it's divisible by 3, you'll get the first message, and if it's *also* divisible by 2 you'll also get the second message.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations of when to print output are independent, ie. they execute one after the other. Hence you get multiple lines of output.

In order to implement the "instead" requirements, you need to re-order them and link them:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by two and three");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by three");
    } else if (i % 2 === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is even" );
    } else {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is odd");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a valid code with `else if` after just `else`

Comment: Well spotted - my mistake. I've fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `if` conditions are satisfied, hence you are getting repetitions. Try moving the if-else around a bit:-

```
if (i % 2 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by two and three");
} else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by three");
} else if (i % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is even");
} else {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is odd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because if a value is divisible by 6 it is also even and divisible by 3. To fix it you should check 6 first and check for 2 and 3 only in the `else` branch

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if(i % 2 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by two and three");
  }
  else {
      if(i % 2 === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is even" );
      } else {
        if(i % 3 === 0) {
          console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by three");
        }
        else {
          console.log("The number " + i + " is odd");
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of your conditional statements is important. 
The below code should give result you expect.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
       console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by two and three");
    }   
    else if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is divisible by three");
    }
    else if(i % 2 === 0) {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is even" );
    } 
   else {
        console.log("The number " + i + " is odd");
    }
}
```